# Generate number in sequence insted of Random number in Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, paperjs

On click  I want to access the keyData array but on click random number is generated how can I access elements of array  keyData in the sequence not in random Like on first click first element is accessed and on sthe econd click the second element is accessed ,and so on. AThiscode is from Paper js lib.

I want to change this randomNumber with sequence of numbers as mentioned above. I think using loop is not the solution.

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
            var maxPoint = new Point(view.size.width, view.size.height);
            var randomPoint = Point.random();
            var point = maxPoint * randomPoint;
            var newCircle = new Path.Circle(point, 250);
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 27);
            newCircle.fillColor = keyData[randomNumber].color;
            keyData[randomNumber].sound.play();
            circles.push(newCircle);
    }
```

Comment: Please share what you've tried and where you've stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a variable called number outside the function, replace randomnumber in the function with number and increment number on each click.

Note, it appears that keyData has entries with index 0-26 so you need to ensure number does not go above that, hence the % in the click event. Also, the color and sound will be non-random but the center point of the circle still is.

```
<button onclick="onKeyDown(event);">Click me to go to create the next circle</button> 
<script>
var number=0;
function onKeyDown(event) {
            var maxPoint = new Point(view.size.width, view.size.height);
            var randomPoint = Point.random();
            var point = maxPoint * randomPoint;
            var newCircle = new Path.Circle(point, 250);
            newCircle.fillColor = keyData[number].color;
            keyData[number].sound.play();
            circles.push(newCircle);
            //set up for the next time
            number = (number + 1)%27;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the previous answer, you have to use a counter.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/bVE9b4MwEP0rJ0sV0CCUpQtRp3TrgtRuhMExl2LhnCtjQlLEf69tCkrVWrJk37t7H/bIiJ+R5eytRSsaljKha39XaEHoniwaeIbt7mAO5LfQ1Flo8fbCLXdI6Yvg1ujalTY5RAbrCKb0L3BDpfTwP3ZUPTrEA9UqdupJWKkJNL06RT1QjBckm8C4MMx+JNV4dW4Wxw+Lw0whfdhm97udcNhLIxS6EXeGgtsmmytxoSXZzHCq9TlO4BEuEoesk1+YwtM2WZlWjuwkldr7GI7tR7YMhqospLsTD+42m1CZlpTBgVd9x6uN75NZl9W9TWGw64B78mh9uk8/kc/uBHreAE2zQ/eRR4O8DV0dy8tq+gY=) demonstrating a simplified solution.

```js
let counter = 0;

const keyData = [
    { color: 'red' },
    { color: 'yellow' },
    { color: 'blue' }
];

function onKeyDown(event) {
    const index = counter % keyData.length;
    const newCircle = new Path.Circle(Point.random() * view.size, 50);
    newCircle.fillColor = keyData[index].color;
    counter++;
}
```